# Get unicode text when Python encode utf-8

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I use `Wechat Public platform` to send some content. And the code is:

```
# coding:utf-8
import os
import urllib2
import json
import httplib2)    

content = "一些中文"

body = {
    "touser":"abcdefg",
    "msgtype":"text",
    "text":
    {
            "content": content
    }
}

access_token = '1234567890'
req_url = 'https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/message/custom/send?access_token=' + access_token
method = 'POST'
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
headers['Accept-Charset'] = 'encoding=utf-8'
resp, token = http_obj.request(req_url, method, headers=headers, body=json.dumps(body))
```

I receive **\u4e00\u4e9b\u4e2d\u6587** not when I run **一些中文** the program. What should I do if I want to receive **一些中文**?? Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is the purpose of `.encode(type)`?  `type` is a reserved Python word (and I also don't see you define it anywhere)

Comment: Also, yuck.  Python doesn't like your "some Chinese".  It gives me an unsupported type error :(

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited the code just now, and remove some code. But it doesn't effective.

Comment: Try using `gbk` if you're on Windows for your Chinese encoding.  See this answer for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688020/how-to-print-chinese-word-in-my-code-using-python

Comment: Using decode for pythons strings, on the receiving end, might be relevant, see this answer (though about Hebrew characters, it's about the same with needing to print out Unicode): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18079690/using-hebrew-on-python/18080334#18080334

Comment: What's the problem? In JSON, `"\u4e00\u4e9b\u4e2d\u6587"` is absolutely identical to `"一些中文"`. Note also that the `Accept-Charset` header, if passed, should not contain `encoding=`; it should be superfluous in any case as UTF-8 is the default encoding for JSON (and the header itself is somewhat archaic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump the body as following:

```
json.dumps(body, ensure_ascii=False)
```

From python docs (https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

If ensure_ascii is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str instance consisting of ASCII characters only. If ensure_ascii is False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the encoding parameter is used. Unless fp.write() explicitly understands unicode (as in codecs.getwriter()) this is likely to cause an error.

Comment: json.dumps(body, encoding='utf-8', ensure_ascii=False)

Comment: The default encoding is 'utf-8'.
`json.dumps(obj, skipkeys=False, ensure_ascii=True, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, encoding="utf-8", default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)`